# Laravel Dompdf generate pdf Error

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Iam already use Laravel 5.1 and Dompdf (barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).
I just want to generate pdf from this text:

> ţăaţţi sÎ

then the generated text on my pdf:

> ??a??i s

Code:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML("ţăaţţi sÎ");
$pdf->setPaper('a4')->setOrientation('landscape')->stream();
return $pdf->stream();
```

What can i do, to fix this problem?
I hope someone can help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is handling the special chars with `dom_pdf`.

Please try adding UTF-8 to the `load_html()` function:

```
$html = 'ţăaţţi sÎ';
$dompdf->load_html($html,'UTF-8');
```

If this doesn't work out, i think you might need to adjust the dompdf config and enable Unicode:

`dompdf_config.inc.php`

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
```

---

If the content is still not correct, try to convert it:

`$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');`

And on the HTML and CSS side of things, make sure your are rendering in UTF-8, while using a font, which supports the symbols and chars.

`*{ font-family: DejaVu Sans, font-size: 12px;}`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: $html = 'ţăaţţi sÎ';
$dompdf->load_html($html,'UTF-8'); Thats not work, and my config is good :(